# Is there any way to reveal the type of a node in shader editor?

Tags: node-editor, shader-nodes

I cannot reveal the node type of nodes when they was renamed. Is there a way to check is? I don't really understand, why Blender does not display it on the node itself, or in its properties, or a popup text or other way.

Comment: Select the Node, hit the 'N' key to bring up the sidebar. On the Node tab the 'Name' field shows the node type and the 'Label' shows the renamed label.

Comment: @JohnEason .. I think that constitutes a full  answer? I can imagine others might be similarly mystified, and find your info. useful.

Comment: @RobinBetts Question is already closed to answers as it's been answered before: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251143/what-shader-node-is-it Mind you the answers in that posting do seem to be making something of a meal of it to coin a phrase! :^)

Comment: Ahhh. OK, thanks, @John