# What is the shortcut to add a new node?

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

Starting to mess with geometry nodes, I am. While watching a tutorial I see the guy just opens a search to find the node he wants to add to the process. In grasshopper we would double-click to add a "node" like this, but i am not able to do it hitting any number of keys I have tried so far. I will keep searching, but thanks in advance for any help/support.

thanks

Comment: Should just be Shift+A, same hotkey for making a new object in object mode

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, then choose a node from the menu:

[image]

- <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>S</kbd>, then start typing the name of the node:

[image]

- **In Blender 4**: <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and start typing immediately. Be careful not to move your mouse too much before typing the name of the node:

[image]

- **Recommended** (Blender 3.3+): drag your mouse from a socket of **any** node as if you were about to create a new link, but release your mouse when it's not above any socket it could connect to, which is indicated by a "+" sign meaning it will add a new node:

[image]

I recommend this because it suggests more nodes than above options and solves problems like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/251143/60486), keep in mind, however, that it's contextual: the popup will prioritize (put on top) nodes/inputs with the same type as the one you're dragging. It will also filter out nodes that don't can't work connected to the link you're currently creating:

- dragging (left) from an input will allow you to search only outputs,
- dragging (right) from an output will allow you to search only inputs,
- dragging from a green output will only suggest nodes that have a green input etc.

[image]

- Speedrun technique: when at least one node is selected, you can press:

  - <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> to connect selected node to new *Math: Add* node,
  - <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad -</kbd> *Math: Subtract*,
  - <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad *</kbd> *Math: Multiply*,
  - <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad /</kbd> *Math: Divide*,

The order of multiple nodes is based on their vertical position:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Blender has several hundreds of hotkeys and several different keymap configurations. Every hotkey may also be changed and additional hotkeys can be created by add-ons as well as the user. It would make little sense to ask about each one on Blender Stack Exchange.

Fun fact: I count 2863 active keymap items in every keymap of 'Blender' keyconfig with a Python script. Those include same hotkeys repeating in different contexts though.

It is better to have a way of finding out about hotkeys. There are several ways.

- You can just hover your mouse over some button or menu and the hotkey for it will be displayed in the tooltip:

[image]
[image]

- Hotkeys are also displayed in the menus:

[image]

- You can see them in the search menu( <kbd>F3</kbd> ):

[image]

- You can also explore the keymap itself in the Preferences( <kbd>F4</kbd>   ->   <kbd>P</kbd> ):

[image]

- You can also see [Common Shortcuts](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/keymap/introduction.html) section in the manual.

Answer (score -3):

> #### [image: AI Icon] Warning, Potential AI generated content⚠️
>
> **This post is suspected to have been generated with the help of an artificial intelligence, chat bot, or other language model tools without proper attribution.**
>
> There is reason to believe this post was not written by a human due to its structure, and grammatical construction, and has been marked by our community.
> Current AI chat bots are a language models, that means they are like a parrot, they can mimic human language well, but they are built to write **seemingly** logical, **seemingly** factual grammatically valid text, rather than actually **be correct**, like a human would.
> The veracity of the following content cannot be ascertained.
> See the [Concerns regarding AI generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396).

I said to ChatGPT

> User: I'm watching a tutorial where a guy just adds a node ("mesh island" is the name of the node) by doing something to open up a search menu. do you know what im talking about? I cant figure out how he did it

It's <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, I almost started into the documentation, but gpt is my fav.

Comment: or just drag a noodle and drop it in 'mid air', and you'll be offered a search.