How do I create a procedural radial gradient on a flat ring?
I have a Geometry Nodes setup for a procedural ring with adjustable vertex count, outer radius, and thickness. I want to shade it with a smooth gradient between one adjustable color at the inner and outer edges and a second adjustable color in the middle. How do I do that? I haven't been able to figure out a setup that works.
My Geometry Nodes setup:

The kind of gradient I want to achieve:


You need to tell the shader what are the outer and inner radii or outer radius and thickness, either by using drivers, or by storing as attributes (in the latter case there's a lot of data duplication, but usually it doesn't matter for performance):

Then you can calculate the distance to edge in various ways...



What is the "Length" node in your texture setup? I can't find it in Blender...

@Lawton https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/264457/60486
